# perl - processing template files to html

Tags: perl, templates, mod-perl2

I am new to web programming but have experience working on perl scripts that have to do with file processing. Recently got a copy of MVC project source code. As I am trying to come to terms with template files, control & view modules, one question that came across is:

1. I see the template file in .tt extension(mypage.tt), there is the control module in .pm extension(MyPage.pm)) containing handler function to call the template and call to process subroutine in the View module(View.pm). But how does it generate .pl or html. I can't seem to find a perl executable or html file in the project. What should i enter in my url under

localhost/myapp/....

to call execute the script

I have loaded the project in my local directory with apache & mod_perl installed. Would be helpful if someone can explain if i need to write a perl script to call the handler function in the .pm file and generate the html if that's not too much to ask for :).

Answer (score 1):

You project, if it is really a mod_perl app will have Apache configuration that maps URLs to handler methods.

Template files with a .tt extension typically are from the Template Toolkit, and perform their generation step by calling a method called process() on an instance of Template.

So you need to find the Apache handlers. They will tell you which methods are running, and then you can read hose methods to see how the template toolkit is being employed to generate the HTML.